# Getting Result from Activity Started with SearchManager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-searchmanager

I am following this [relatively simple tutorial](http://blog.dpdearing.com/2011/05/getting-android-to-call-onactivityresult-after-onsearchrequested/) on how to manually start a `SearchableActivity` so that I can get a `result` back from it.

He is basically setting up the **base** `Activity` (Activity A) as the searchable activity (in the manifest), so that it receives the search intent and then manually launch real Search `Activity` (Activity B) with `startActivityForResult`,

After altering the manifests, he only has one block of code. My question:

Where do you put this code?

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
   // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
   if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
     String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
     // manually launch the real search activity
     final Intent searchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
           MySearchActivity.class);
     // add query to the Intent Extras
     searchIntent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
     startActivityForResult(searchIntent, ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
   }
```

`Activity` A or B?  And where do you call it?

**EXTRA INFO - How I am doing it currently - does this get cut out?**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    setupNewSearchView(searchItem, searchManager);
}

return true;
```

}

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupNewSearchView(final MenuItem searchItem, SearchManager searchManager) {
    android.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.widget.SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make Activity(A) singleInstance/singleTop in manifest.xml `android:launchMode="singleInstance|singleTop"`
then use the `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` from Activity(A) to handleIntent(intent)

Edit:
ActivityA.java

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

Please read this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) to get full clear view of what happening

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  Where does `onNewIntent()` get called?  I'm assuming in `Activity` A.  But where? When `Activity` A starts (onCreate)?  Or where the `SearchManager` normally gets called?

Comment: when you search (after writing text in the searchView and pressed search button on keyboard) the Android system will start a new instance of the Activity(A) (new Activity(A) with a Intent with search action), but and because we used 'singleInstance' the onNewIntent function on Activity(A) will be called with the search action intent

Comment: Thanks for all of your help again.  I understand what you are saying.  But still unclear as to the "where".  You said "It will be called with the search action intent".  Right now, I handle this (I believe) in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.  I have added that code above to how I am doing this BEFORE the needed change.  Is there where I need to call it? (and remove what I have already done then?)

Comment: Thanks, I got it.  I see what is happening.  I just wasn't passing the query on to the `SearchableActivity`.